# How to draw interactively with Pen on a Morph in Squeak?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak, pen, morphic

It can't get the Pen to work properly in a Morph.

I arrived at the snippet below but I don't understand how to update the view of the Morph after I moved the pen. I tried to send "changed" in various (sm, pen, (sm owner)) object but it does not solve it.

In the snippet below the line gets drawn if I resize the window. Or, also, if i put "openInWindow" as last line.

```
sm := SketchMorph new.
sm clearExtent: 600@600 fillColor: (Color yellow) darker darker.
sm position: 100@100.
sm openInWindow. 
pen := sm penOnMyForm.
pen defaultNib: 4; color: (Color red).
pen up.
pen goto: 10@10. 
pen down.
pen goto: 100@100.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message you should send to the `SketchMorph`, instead of `#layoutChanged`, is

```
sm revealPenStrokes
```

which is -pun intended- quite intention revealing; isn't it?

## How did I find it

Using the hint provided by Nicola, I debugged `sm layoutChanged` trying to understand why it showed the line. I had tried `sm changed` before with no luck, so I knew that the clue had to be in `generateRotatedForm`. And since this method redefines the ivar `rotatedForm`, I looked for all methods that changed it, as I suspected that the problem was in some cache not being invalidated by `changed`. Quickly enough, the selector `revealPenStrokes` emerged victorious from the rather short list of methods modifying `rotatedForm`.

Comment: Hi @Leandro definitely this is the proper method, thank you!  It is quite hard to read those long lists in the System Browser. If I had the possibility of filtering the method list by "pen" i would not have missed it. I think Pharo has a similar selector for Categories, I will look around to see if Squeak has somoething similar.

Comment: @NicolaMingotti Thanks for the comment. I had to do some work to find the selector (I'm not a Squeak user), so I've added a description of the steps I followed, which could be more useful than telling just the selector.

Answer (score 1):

I found the method, but I don't understand the logic.

Just add this at the end.

```
sm layoutChanged.
pen goto: 150@100.
sm layoutChanged.
" ... and so on "
```

If I look into the "layoutChanged" definition and I try to send those methods myself I see the command that rules is "generateRotatedForm" ... Umm ... why ?

If some Morphic expert would like to shed some light into this I would be grateful.

bye
Nicola